# How to remove drawer icon from appbar when the screen size is large and display it when the screen size is small | Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, dart, web, responsive, flutter-web

I'm creating a flutter web app, i have some option in top of the page such as about, contact. My problem is i want to show these option in Appbar when displaying in large screen and for mobile i want to put it inside drawer. I implement it using the below code, but the drawer icon is always there in large and small screens. I don't want to show it in large screen.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Home"),
      ),
      drawer: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) {
          if (constraints.maxWidth < 768) {
            return Drawer();
          } else {
            return SizedBox();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How can i Implement this in correct way

Answer (score 0):

You can identify device type with below code

```
 static bool isMobile(BuildContext context) =>
      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width < 650;

  static bool isTablet(BuildContext context) =>
      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width < 1100 &&
      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width >= 650;

  static bool isDesktop(BuildContext context) =>
      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width >= 1100;
```

And use like this

```
isMobile(context) ? Drawer() : SizedBox(),
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [responsive_builder](https://pub.dev/packages/responsive_builder).

```
class NavBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const NavBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScreenTypeLayout(
      mobile: NavBarMobile(),  // this will automatic take screensize and show the Nav bar accordingly 
      tablet: NavBarDesktop(),
    );
  }
}
```

in `NavBarDesktop()`

```
Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Text("Logo Here"),
            Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Icon(
                        Icons.person,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "  About Me",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  style: ButtonStyle(padding: MaterialStateProperty.all<EdgeInsets>(EdgeInsets.all(20))),
                ),
                
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Icon(
                        Icons.cycle,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "  Blog",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  style: ButtonStyle(padding: MaterialStateProperty.all<EdgeInsets>(EdgeInsets.all(20))),
                ),
                
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Icon(
                        Icons.cycle,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "  Contact Me",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  style: ButtonStyle(padding: MaterialStateProperty.all<EdgeInsets>(EdgeInsets.all(20))),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

and in `NavBarMobile()`

```
Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          OutlineButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer();
            },
            hoverColor: Colors.black,
            child: Text("Menu"),
          ),
          Text("Logo Here")
        ],
      ),
```

and `Drawer`:

```
Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        // Important: Remove any padding from the ListView.
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: <Widget>[
          DrawerHeader(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
            child: Text('Drawer Header'),
          ),
          
          ListTile(
            title: Text('About Me'),
            onTap: () {
              // Update the state of the app.
              // ...
            },
          ),
          
          ListTile(
            title: Text('Blog'),
            onTap: () {
              // Update the state of the app.
              // ...
            },
          ),
          
          ListTile(
            title: Text('Contact Me'),
            onTap: () {
              // Update the state of the app.
              // ...
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

In `scaffold` add this line so that if user slide from right than Drawer do not open in web

```
endDrawerEnableOpenDragGesture: false,
```

Answer (score 0):

you can easily assign as follows:

```
 class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MainScreenState createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SizeConfig().init(context);
    return Scaffold(
      endDrawerEnableOpenDragGesture: false,
      body: Container(
        height: SizeConfig.screenHeight,
        width: SizeConfig.screenWidth,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            if (Responsive.isDesktop(context))
              AppBar()
            else
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                child: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer();
                  },
                  hoverColor: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```